# How to display array in table format that has fields before each other in php

Tags: php, arrays, loops, object, iteration

I have an array like this.

```
$array[0]   =   'email1';
$array[1]   =   'email2';
$array[2]   =   'email3';
$array[3]   =   'mobile1';
$array[4]   =   'mobile2';
$array[5]   =   'mobile3';
$array[6]   =   'email1_c';
$array[7]   =   'email2_c';
$array[8]   =   'email3_c';
$array[9]   =   'mobile1_c';
$array[10]  =   'mobile2_c';
$array[11]  =   'mobile3_c';
```

Now i want to dispay a table like this

```
--------------------------------
email1      |       email1_c
email2      |       email2_c
email3      |       email3_c
mobile1     |       mobile1_c
mobile2     |       mobile2_c
mobile3     |       mobile3_c
```

Now when i loop through the array i get this

```
--------------------------------
email1      |       email2
email3      |       mobile1
mobile2     |       mobile3
email1_c    |       email2_c
email2_c    |       mobile1_c
mobile1_c   |       mobile3_c
```

Now this is not what i want and i know simple looping wont do what i want.
So is there any alternative way to achieve this.

Note : The data given is only sample data. I am actually working in a pre-defined 
template in wordpress and wordpress simply throw me an object so i can use it. In 
the backend i have tried everything even sorting but i get the data like above.
I need alternative so i can change easily and i dont want to modify default files.

Comment: can you not get the list of number of elements, and then have a `</ul>` at the endof `length/2` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that it depends on an offset value. As you have it shown that value would be six:

```
$html = "<table>\n";
$offset = 6;
for ($i=0; $i<=5; $i++){
    $html .= "<tr><td>".$array[$i]."</td><td>".$array[$i + $offset]."</td></tr>\n";
}
$html .= "</table>\n";
```

Depending on what you need you might need to dynamically calculate the offset. For example:

```
$offset = count($array)/2;
```

Comment: what if i have object instead of array

Comment: Can you edit your answer to provide some information about the object. It really depends on how it's structured.